# How can I allocate more than 2GB of memory to a process in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, memory, process

I am running a program that builds a very large object, and I would greatly benefit from allocating more than 2GB of memory to this process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even though it may make your program easier to write, allocating 2GB+ chunks of memory will certainly lead to a poorer application for your user.

Comment: How do you build a 2GB object?

Comment: @gabe an array is the most obvious example

Comment: @David: I would have assumed that the OP would have said "a very large array" if that were the case, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be referring to the 2gb limit on virtual memory in 32 bit Windows. You can't get around this limit on a 32 bit system.

Comment: You can use /3gb switch in boot.ini config and mark process "Large address space aware"... but trying to load 2GB in memory on 32bit OS is not an easy task for either native or managed code.

Comment: @alexei The machine's admin can do /3gb but an app can't

Answer (score 6):

You cannot allocate a single object (or an array) that is greater than 2GB, this is a CLR limitation. You'll have to split up the object into pieces.

Comment: so suppose I have a 3GB object that I split into 6 0.5GB objects, wouldn't that still go over the 2GB process limit? Thanks again.

Comment: And, TBH, if you are trying to manage an object this size, you need to do some rethinking.

Comment: @Schroedingers Cat It's perfectly reasonable to want to allocate huge objects for some algorithms.

Comment: @Isaac Newton - Of course it would go over the 3.0GB limit.  You cannot load more then 2GB in the virutal memory on a 32-bit operating system unless you use the /3gb switch.  Unless you have full control over the system, then your design is flawed, if your loading that much information into your application.

Comment: Use 64-bit Windows and then you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @paul what if end user is running 32 bit system?

Comment: @David Then, you're stuck with the 2GB limit. Changing the user's boot settings is not a great thing to be doing in a setup routine. You *could* split your app into multiple processes, which would get you all the VA space you want, or you can say 64-bit only.

Comment: @paul changing user's boot settings would count as malware

Comment: @David Well, I mean there *are* legit situations where that might be reasonable - if your software costs > $10K and comes with its own pre-configured machine (think highly specialized industrial apps), it might be reasonable, so it's at least worth knowing about. But it's almost certainly not the case with the majority of us

Answer (score 5):

.NET Framework 4.5 allows creating arrays larger than 2GB on 64 bit platforms. This feature is not on by default, it has to be enabled via config file using the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is that the only way? I really don't want to switch to VS2012 if I don't have to.